# How do I get the total sum in ng-init and ng-repeat - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

Having a problem with in ng-init and ng-repeat  angularjs

i'm trying to loop the fields rates to get the total

for example this is my table

**nane** +++++++**id**+++++++**rate**

**joe** +++++++++**1**+++++++**3**

**joe** +++++++++**2**+++++++**3**

**joe** +++++++++**3**+++++++**3**

**joe** +++++++++**4**+++++++**3**

this my code.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>rate</td>

</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="item in videos">
<td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td ng-init="videos.total.rate = videos.total.rate + item.rate">{{item.rate}}</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Total</td>
  <td>{{videos.total.rate}}</td>

</tr>
```

**The Result that I get is 3333 instead of 12** when added all together

this is the line with problem

```
<td ng-init="videos.total.rate = videos.total.rate + item.rate">{{item.rate}}</td>
```

if i change it to a number it works fine.

```
<td ng-init="videos.total.rate = videos.total.rate + 3">{{item.rate}}</td>
```

your help would be great.thanks

Comment: What are the values of the individual rates?  I suspect that `ng-init` won't work for your case.

Comment: they are all 3333 for rate

Comment: I don't think that `ng-init` is seeing each new item as `ng-repeat` iterates.  Yoh might want to move the summation logic into your controller.

Comment: how do i cast or parse  it to int it seems to concatenate 3 to 3333 instead of adding 3+3+3+3 to give me the total of 12.

Comment: `<td ng-init="videos.total.rate = videos.total.rate + item.rate">{{item.rate}}</td>
`                           -------------- `<td ng-init="videos.total.rate = videos.total.rate + This==>  item.rate <=== This is the problem i think it come back as a string ">{{item.rate}}</td>
`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in controller.

JS

```
   $scope.RateTotal= 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $scope.RateTotal= $scope.RateTotal + data[i].rate;
   }
```

HTML

```
  <p>{{RateTotal}}</p>
```

---

Option above is better, but if you want use **[ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)** use something like this.

```
<table ng-init="RateTotal = 0">
 <thead>
<th>Rate</th>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in videos">
<td ng-init="$parent.RateTotal= $parent.RateTotal + item.rate">{{item.rate}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>{{RateTotal}}</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

P.S.

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into
>   your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such
>   as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo
>   below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these
>   few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize
>   values on a scope. - [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: this still returns 03333 as the result.

Comment: Probably because these values are strings instead numbers. Have you checked it out?

Comment: @user1697533 Are you in the meantime managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

move this logic into the controller. That is what it is for. The view should be displaying data.

Now you have to worry about how to cast strings to an integer and writing 4x more code in a language that angular must interpret into javascript.

The complexity you are adding here is going to be fun to maintain.

---

but you probably want to continue doing it wrong, in which case this should work: `<table ng-init='videos.total = {"rate": 0}'>`

Comment: 6 hrs ago i was trying  to do the same thing, but no luck. just going sleep now, i didn't think it's gonna be  this hard or i'm just tired to figure it out.

Comment: if change it to `<table ng-init='videos.total = {"rate": 0}'>` i get the result as  03333

Comment: that sucks, move the sum logic to the controller and call it a day. you can do it with a `map` and a `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

Define a filter to calculate the total:

```
app.filter('calculateRateTotal',function(){
    return function(input){
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach(input,function(value,key){
            total = total+value.rate;
        });
        return total;
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<td ng-bind="videos | calculateRateTotal"></td>
```

Comment: woah, did we forget how to write code? Do you create a new angular filter every time you need to do something in the controller?

Comment: This will recalculate every digest. With small lists its ok, but with large lists its not a good ideia...

Answer (score 0):

After 10hrs of no luck just my managed to get it right. turned to be very simple.

This is the code.

**In the Controller added**

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.videos.length; i++){
    var item = $scope.videos[i];
    total += (item.rate*1);
}
return total;   }
```

**And HTML**

```
<table>

        <tr>
            <th>Rate</th>
        </tr>


        <tr ng-repeat="item in videos">
            <td>{{item.rate}}</td>

        </tr>           
        <tr>              
            <td>Total: {{ getTotal() }}</td> 
        </tr>

    </table>
```

**Thanks everyone for helping**