# angular 7 html variable initialization

Tags: angular

I'm sure this is a simple solution but really couldn't find anything online or I kept getting sent down the wrong rabbit holes...

I just want to do a simple loop and add the items to a variable for display purpose only..

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div> {{ item.cost }} </div>
<div>
```

then outside the loop initialize a variable and within the loop and increment it

```
set totalCost=0
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div> {{ item.cost }} </div>
   set totalCost = totalCost + item.cost
<div>
```

so I tried ngInit and various flavors to no avail.  such as [How do I get the total sum in ng-init and ng-repeat - angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088788/how-do-i-get-the-total-sum-in-ng-init-and-ng-repeat-angularjs)

Comment: Why not initialize this variable in component?

Comment: You can do the calculations/assignment in component. Not in the HTML

Comment: If you want to do it in the view can do `<div (click)="totalcost = totalcost + item.cost">` No need to set it to 0 first.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the *component*, NOT the view.

A one-liner:

```
totalCost = items.reduce((result, item) => result + item.cost, 0);
```

Comment: Nice: simple test `[1,2,3,4].reduce((result, item) => result + item, 0);` => `10` :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this in your `HTML` file, but rather do something like following

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div> {{ item.cost }} </div>
<div>
   <div> {{getTotalCost()}} </div>
```

and in the `.ts` file of your component write the function

```html
getTotalCost(){
// assuming you have a list of objects
let total = 0;
this.items.foreach(item=>{
total+= item.cost;
});
return total;
}
```